# Linq Non-static Methord Requires A Target

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Not sure why but this line is causing me issues:

```
public void AddToCart(Product product)
{
    var cartItem = storeDB.Carts.SingleOrDefault((c.productID) == product.ProductID);
}
```

I'm calling this from a controller.

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int productID)
{
    var addedProduct = storeDB.Products.Find(productID);

    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContent);

    cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: what is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Please supply some context for this: are you calling this from a static methid? what is `ShoppingCartID`?

Comment: Possibly `product`  is null

Comment: After your edit this wouldn't even compile, because `c =>` is gone.

Comment: It says "Linq Non-static Methord Requires A Target".

Comment: Try replacing `(c.productID)` with `c => c.productID`. Might also place a break point on the LINQ statement and make sure `product.ProductID` has a valid value in it right before executing it.

Comment: Please provide some more information on the issue you are facing it is difficult for us to identify your issue simply by looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your first query, to `storeDB.Products`, is returning a null value (because the entity you're trying to find was not found). Subsequently, `addedProduct` is null, and you try to reference it in the other LINQ statement, which throws a null reference exception.

Apparently, a null reference exception thrown in the expression inside a LINQ statement that's being used with your `storeDB` context, manifests as the "Method Requires a Target" exception you're getting.

Try checking for `null` before passing it to the `AddToCart` method and using it in that LINQ statement.

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int productID)
{
    var addedProduct = storeDB.Products.Find(productID);

    if (addedProduct == null)
    {
        // take some appropriate action here
        // or possibly throw an exception (can't add a missing product to the cart)
    }

    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContent);

    cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Also, your code won't compile after your first edit. You need to add `c =>` back in.

```
var cartItem = storeDB.Carts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.productID == product.ProductID);
```